# Search and replace special characters (å,ä,ö) for image links only in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, replace, special-characters

I need to replace the special characters å,ä,ö (with a or o) within a MySQL database. How can I apply this search and replace only to affect image links? The images have either jpeg or jpg extension.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate that some effort has been attempted.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Managed to solve it however. See code below.

Comment: Lack of any code related to your question makes it difficult to tailor a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

update your column with the desired data. Use a sequence of replaces, or write a custom function:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET link=REPLACE(link, 'ä,', 'a');
```

If your links are scattered in text, you can use substring_index to break it apart from the text using www. as the first delimiter, .jpg as the second, and re-concatenate with the rest of the text after replacing

```
set @a='sömetext www.göögle.com.jpg sömetext';
select concat(
substring_index(@a, 'www.', 1),
 'www.',
replace(substring_index(substring_index(@a, '.jpg', 1), 'www.', -1), 'ö','o'),
 '.jpg',
 substring_index(@a, '.jpg', -1)
);

>sömetext www.google.com.jpg sömetext
```

Comment: I tried UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE ('meta_value', 'ä', 'a'); but this replaced all the affected rows with "meta_value". I have to admit I'm not very experienced with writing SQL queries :)

Comment: @StaffanEstberg don't quote the column name, my bad - hope you had a backup :P

Comment: Haha I did no worries :) I actually managed to solve it just now. See code below.

Answer (score 1):

Solved -

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value, 'å', 'a') , 'ä', 'a') , 'ö', 'o')
WHERE LOWER(RIGHT(meta_value, 5)) = '.jpeg'
   OR LOWER(RIGHT(meta_value, 4)) IN ('.jpg', '.gif', '.png')
```

You might want to squeeze in an additional parameter to look for and replace capital letters.

Comment: nice set of replaces there :)